# Why my laptop battery is declared dead but lasted several hours shortly before?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

I recently bought a second hand Lenovo X230 laptop, and used it without problem on the battery. However at some point the battery was low and I shut down the computer and plugged it for the night. After that, it never powered up again on the battery, it now always have to be plugged. It won't do nothing if I press the power button if it's unplugged. If I plug it, it runs normally, but if I unplug it while the computer is on, it immediately powers off, confirming the battery is not active.

On Windows, Lenovo's power manager tell me the battery is at its end of life and needs to be changed. This is weird as I was able to use it for several hours on the battery. On Linux, it's pretty much the same, but I can have a bit more information:

```
$ grep . /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/* 2>/dev/null
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/alarm:2649000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity:95
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity_level:Critical
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count:0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full:52990000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design:62640000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now:50610000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer:SANYO
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name:45N1172
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now:0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/present:1
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/serial_number:11604
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status:Unknown
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/technology:Li-ion
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/type:Battery
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Unknown
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=10800000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=12232000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW=0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN=62640000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=52990000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_NOW=50610000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=95
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Critical
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=45N1172
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=SANYO
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=11604
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/voltage_min_design:10800000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/voltage_now:12232000
```

`energy_now` is 95% of `energy_full`, which in turns is 85% of `energy_full_design`. This doesn't sound like an end-of-life battery, but still acts like one. The main problem seems to be that `capacity_level:Critical`, but nothing else looks alarming from my understanding.

So is it possible that maybe the computer didn't charge the battery somehow and that reported numbers are plain wrong, or that the battery wrongfully reports a critical level preventing the computer to power on?

Comment: The solution would be better as an answer, which you could then accept to indicate that the problem is solved.  As part of the question, it is confusing.

Answer (score -1):

A number of things could be wrong.  Batteries have gotten much cheaper.  I recommend that you save yourself lots of frustration and simply buy another battery and try that solution.  That is relatively quick and easy, and a common (or high probability) solution, compared to the next steps if that doesn't work.

Other steps, bad contacts, OS needs recalibration, power supply running in airplane mode, ...

Comment: This does not answer the question. (I expect the answer has to do with a bad cell, or maybe a faulty chip in the battery, but I'm not expert..)

Comment: @Davidgo, I worked for years in computer repair and even owned my own computer repair company for a time.  So you can mark me down all you want, but I'm willing to bet I've fixed hundreds of more problems than you and frankly your opinion is only that.

Comment: I agree with @davidgo here, "buy a new battery" is not the kind of answer I'm expecting here. The seller already offered to buy me a compatible battery, but his supplier announces a 3 weeks delay, and the laptop is pretty more or less useless for my needs without a battery. I just want to check if this battery that I used for several hours in a row can be repaired.

Comment: There is apparently a "battery reset" procedure - I wonder if it could help. Page is a bit messed up at the top but have a look at https://www.thinkscopes.com/2013/04/06/battery-reset-procedure-for-thinkpad/

Comment: @davidgo: Already tried that, even if I think that procedure is just to have more accurate charge percentage. Clicking on the `Continue` button on step 6 just instantaneously shuts down the computer, as it's trying to use the battery instead of the AC power, and can get no power from the battery.

Comment: @liberforce, have you solve this?  If not, and if at some point you get a new battery and it fixes this, then please do me the favor of an up-vote.  Thanks.

Comment: @ElipticalView: Well, yes I got a new battery, and yes, it fixed the problem. But no, as already stated, I don't think your answer deserves an upvote. Imagine I had a problem starting my car, and asked what the problem is, and you replied "buy a new one". I already knew buying a new one would fix the problem, but that was not my question.

Comment: @liberforce, Glad you got your prob fixed.  But -1 for bad Karma, because I never suggested you buy a new computer/car, only a battery.

Comment: @ElipticalView: Please stop acting childishly and move on. This includes: not begging for upvotes when OP already stated that your answer isn't worthwhile, acting ad hominem by downvoting people and not content. Note that I hadn't upvoted your answer, but hadn't downvoted it either. I don't care about your karma "punishments", I'm not here for karma anyway. Closed topic for me.

Comment: @liberforce Bottom line: My answer solved your problem.  

Really, you come here and ask for help, and you get it for free.  

You don't follow the rules, and extend your question in a new answer, something totally inappropriate.  

And you treat the people who help you with disrespect.  

What are you thinking?  

Finally, you use resort to name-calling.  In regards to "childishly", do you know what projection is?  I do.  You should look it up and think about it.

Glad you fixed your problem.  Next time fix it yourself.

Comment: @liberforce, Furthermore, since you brought up car batteries, I know quite a bit about that too.  Some people foolishly spend countless hours with a starting problem chasing all the wrong things, like the starter motor, the starter relay, the key switch or the computer.  Yes flaky batteries can cause people to think that something else is wrong.  30 years ago I too was fooled by this.  But if a battery is older, then your best bet to is simply buy a new one.  If there was something else wrong at least you have eliminated the possible battery issues. I've worked in elec. repair much of my life.

Comment: And in that time I've resolved all kinds of electronic and electrical problems on equipment small and big.  On more than one occasion, I've been hired to fix critical equipment which had huge factories entirely shut down until it was fixed.  One of the guys I worked for years ago taught me a few things about how to more quickly get stuff working.  One of those things is to get to know the frequency of certain types of failures.  If you have a component that is a common failure, then consider looking at that first, especially if it's relatively cheap.

Comment: @ElipticalView: Ok, here we go again... Your wrongly state your answer fixed my problem. Read my question again: I wanted to know *why* the battery wasn't working, in case the battery was fixable with a technique I didn't know (by software, using a recalibration procedure or something else). The question wasn't "how to make my computer work again".

Comment: Then you say I don't follow the rules by extending my question in an answer. This is plain wrong, and the edit history of the question proves it. I first edited my question to add the new battery characteristics, then someone found it would be better as an answer, so I moved it there. Note that I didn't accept my own answer as it's information and not  the right answer to the problem either. [Answering your own questions is an encouraged practice](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) if you think thay are valuable.

Comment: In other words, don't try to understand the issue.  Don't try to reason it out.  Of course if you're building computers, or working for a company doing this, then perhaps you might want to spend the time to more fully understand the issue.  But in your question I didn't see that you were in that situation, i.e. "I recently bought a second hand Lenovo X230 laptop"

Comment: Liberforce wrote: "Well, yes I got a new battery, and yes, it fixed the problem."

Comment: When I post here, it's indeed because I want to understand the issues.  I don't think of Superuser as a customer service. That's a place to *learn* things.

Comment: Fair enough, you want to understand how the failure occurs. You might want to study a lot of chemistry and some physics at the college level.  I recall that we spent quite a bit of time in my undergraduate honor's chemistry class looking at batteries. The chemistry is quite complex, and I think more than you would think.  It's certainly not simple.  And if any impurities are there, this adds to that complexity.  How batteries fail is a good subject, but this forum is not for chemistry nor physics.

Comment: I didn't think of a chemical problem, but a software one. Because of the numbers reported by the battery (95% capacity, `energy_now` still high and above the `alarm` threshold, but a "critical" `capacity_level`) which looked inconsistent to me. That's why I provided the numbers in case someone more experienced could spot the inconsistencies. I found it weird that a battery would suddenly go from 2 hours of autonomy to down to 0 overnight. The reports I read talk more about the capacity getting lower and lower until it lasts only a few seconds. That's not what happened for me.

Answer (score -1):

After 2 months of struggling, the seller sent me a new battery. Here is the output of the brand new one, just as a comparison:

```
grep . /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/* 2>/dev/null
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/alarm:3108000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity:68
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity_level:Normal
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count:0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full:62160000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design:62160000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now:42490000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer:SANYO
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name:45N1023
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now:12626000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/present:1
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/serial_number: 1839
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status:Discharging
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/technology:Li-ion
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/type:Battery
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Discharging
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=11100000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=11365000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW=12626000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN=62160000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=62160000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_NOW=42490000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=68
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Normal
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=45N1023
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=SANYO
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER= 1839
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/voltage_min_design:11100000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/voltage_now:11365000
```

Comment: Fast forward a few months. The second battery lasted 2 months and died, the same way the previous one. So that most probably is not a problem with the battery but a (software ? hardware ?) problem with the computer that kills the batteries. The seller agreed to provide me another computer.

Comment: The seller told me he would provide another computer and then disappeared. I bought another one, same model, out of frustration. Seems the battery of the newest compluter works fine on the old model. This means I just had bad luck: an old battery dying and a brand new one that died too.